# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x95

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, decode, decoding

I'm trying to decoding a string like this = 0x7E93K2H3....

Here is my codes:

```
x = "0x7E95D1D083818C406489928583948F9240658E8392999094898F8E406B856D6D85848983818C406489928583948F9240658E8392999094898F8E406B856D6D85848983818C406489928583948F924065"
hexstring = x[2:]
bytesobject = bytes.fromhex(hexstring)
asciistring = bytesobject.decode("ascii")
print(asciistring)
```

but, I get "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x95"

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback?

Comment: Every two hex digits represents a byte. The second byte is `0x95` which is out of range of ASCII (0-127). UTF-8 also doesn't work. If you decode this with the `utf-16` decoding, you get `镾탑膃䂌襤薒钃銏敀莎馒钐辉䂎蕫浭蒅莉貁摀銉莅辔䂒蹥銃邙覔躏歀涅蕭覄膃䂌襤薒钃銏敀`, which doesn't error, but appears to be total gibberish (one of those characters isn't even Chinese/Japanese, the second character is Korean)